# How to upload Crashlytics symbols automatically

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

My Android project consists of library and app. The library has C++ code, so it uses NDK support. I am working on integrating Crashlytics into the project, and I want to automatically upload symbols after *release* has been built.

The library's *build.gradle* looks as follows:

```
// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
            '-C', file('../../Android_Jni').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}

task upload {
    doLast {
        println('Uploading...')
        crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease
    }
}

ndkBuild.finalizedBy(upload)

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Uploading seems to work, but it happens both when I build *debug* and *release* flavours (which I select in *Build Variants* in Android Studio).
Is it possible to modify script so that it would only upload symbols after release build has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames && gradle.startParameter.taskNames[0].endsWith('Release') ) {
    ndkBuild.finalizedBy(upload)
}
```